# How to share folders using Oracle, Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: software-center

I use my laptop TOSHIBA, 4gig RAM, more 40gig free disks spaces and Vista Home Premium 64bits with service pack 2. 
I installed Oracle VM VirtalBox with success, after I installed UBUNTU version 8 with success !

I need to transfer files between Vista and UBUNTU on the same laptop, how I can do that ?
Can I use SAMBA ? I try to use SAMBA but it is not success ! How I can install SAMBA on UBUNTU v.8 ?

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy Heron? That's pretty old.

Comment: Agreed, 8.04 LTS is no longer supported.  Support for 10.04 runs out in April next year.  12.04 LTS is supported until 2017 and might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a shared folder on the "host" that is shared by the "guest" Go to https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders for more information as it is rather detailed. The online user manual is here https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html